# How to make slime work in LispCabinet using sbcl?

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime, sbcl

I found out LispCabinet includes slime after installation when I run the clozure-cl version of it (starting with the 3rd button)

http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/5234/lipscabinet.jpg

But when I typy M-x slime in sbcl mode (starting emacs with the 4th button) I receive a never ending message:

```
Polling "c:/DOKUME~1/Administrator/LOKALE~1/Temp/slime.2788".. 
(Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) [38 times]
```

Do I have to install slime by hand in LispCabinet (sbcl version)  or did I install LispCabinet wrong? (I did not do anything fancy during install and tried different options one after the other)